# How to expire div on specific day?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 75 divs and I need to expire that dives on in different dates. I found a js code to do that. but when apply the code to a large number of divs, it may be very difficult. Can I apply the below code in an easy way? If you have any suggestion, please add.

Here is the code I found.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var current = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date("August 07, 2018 12:00:00")
  var expiry2 = new Date("August 09, 2018 12:00:00")

  if (current.getTime() > expiry.getTime()) {
    $('#one').hide();
    $('#two').show();
    $('#three').show();
  } else if (current.getTime() > expiry2.getTime()) {
    $('#one').show();
    $('#two').hide();
    $('#three').show();
  }
};

$('#one').show();
$('#two').show();
$('#three').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" style="display:none">
  <p>content for div #one</p>
</div>
<div id="two" style="display:none">
  <p>content for div #two</p>
</div>
<div id="three" style="display:none">
  <p>content for div #three</p>
</div>
<div id="four" style="display:none">
  <p>content for div four</p>
</div>
<div id="five" style="display:none">
  <p>content for div five</p>
</div>
```

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zEG4g/2543/)

Comment: Do you have a logic on what `div` will expired on a specific date? Like, `div` 1-5 will expire on Mondays, etc

Comment: As I think things like expiration of some div(ex: details about an offer) should be managed by backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a an optimized way to do it using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

We assigned the expiration date to each of the divs by adding `data-expiry="August 07, 2018 12:00:00"` and then retrieve it from the javascript to be compared with the current time.

We also added a class to each div which in this case I used `with-expiry` so that it will be easy to get all the divs and loop each.

Using this approach, your implementation will be flexible and the code will be short.

```js
$(function() {

  var current_date = new Date();

  $(".with-expiry").each(function() {
    var div_date = $(this).data('expiry');

    // wrap in Date class
    div_date = new Date(div_date);

    if (current_date.getTime() > div_date.getTime()) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="with-expiry" style="display:none" data-expiry="August 07, 2018 12:00:00">
  <p>content for div #one</p>
</div>
<div id="two" class="with-expiry" style="display:none" data-expiry="August 08, 2018 12:00:00">
  <p>content for div #two</p>
</div>
<div id="three" class="with-expiry" style="display:none" data-expiry="August 09, 2018 12:00:00">
  <p>content for div #three</p>
</div>
<div id="four" class="with-expiry" style="display:none" data-expiry="August 10, 2018 12:00:00">
  <p>content for div four</p>
</div>
<div id="five" class="with-expiry" style="display:none" data-expiry="August 11, 2018 12:00:00">
  <p>content for div five</p>
</div>
```

Here's a JS fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/569177/

Comment: Yes. It is very easy for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 12pm? Which timezone? While this works, the div will disappear 24 different times during the day depending on the timezone that the the viewer is using.  I recommend rewriting this to use the ISO 8601 date format so that a 12pm Eastern value will correctly auto-hide at 9am Pacific.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a `attibute` to every div to determine every div's **expire date**.

My example is use `data-expire` to set the date of expiration.

While in `onload` method, I check every div's `data-expire` to separate the expired ones and the unexpired ones.

I use **red** words to make them clear to see the difference.

```js
window.onload = function(){

      var current = new Date();
      
      $('.date').each(function(index, event){
        var expire = $(this).data('expire');
        var expireDate = new Date(expire);
        if(expireDate.getTime() <= current.getTime()){
          $(this).css('color', 'red').show();
        }
        else{
          $(this).css('color', 'black').show();
        }
      })
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Red means that date is expired</span>

<div class="date" data-expire="2018-08-01" style="display:none">
    <p>content for div 2018-08-01</p>
</div>
<div class="date" data-expire="2018-08-02" style="display:none">
    <p>content for div 2018-08-02</p>
</div>
<div class="date" data-expire="2018-08-03" style="display:none">
    <p>content for div 2018-08-03</p>
</div>
<div class="date" data-expire="2018-08-04" style="display:none">
    <p>content for div 2018-08-04</p>
</div>
<div class="date" data-expire="2018-08-05" style="display:none">
    <p>content for div 2018-08-05</p>
</div>
<div class="date" data-expire="2018-08-06" style="display:none">
    <p>content for div 2018-08-06</p>
</div>
<div class="date" data-expire="2018-08-07" style="display:none">
    <p>content for div 2018-08-07</p>
</div>
<div class="date" data-expire="2018-08-08" style="display:none">
    <p>content for div 2018-08-08</p>
</div>
<div class="date" data-expire="2018-08-09" style="display:none">
    <p>content for div 2018-08-09</p>
</div>
<div class="date" data-expire="2018-08-10" style="display:none">
    <p>content for div 2018-08-10</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class to do the same, the sample is as follows:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var current = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date("August 07, 2018 12:00:00")
  var expiry2 = new Date("August 09, 2018 12:00:00")

  $(".divON").show();
  if (current.getTime() > expiry.getTime()) {
    $('#one').hide();

  } else if (current.getTime() > expiry2.getTime()) {
    $('#two').show();

  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class='divON' style="display:none">
  <p>content for div #one</p>
</div>
<div id="two" class='divON' style="display:none">
  <p>content for div #two</p>
</div>
<div id="three" class='divON' style="display:none">
  <p>content for div #three</p>
</div>
<div id="four" class='divON' style="display:none">
  <p>content for div four</p>
</div>
<div id="five" class='divON' style="display:none">
  <p>content for div five</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <div id="div0" style="display:none">
            <p>content for div #one</p>
            </div>
            <div id="div1" style="display:none">
            <p>content for div #two</p>
            </div>
            <div id="div2" style="display:none">
            <p>content for div #three</p>
            </div>
            <div id="div3" style="display:none">
            <p>content for div four</p>
            </div>
            <div id="div4" style="display:none">
            <p>content for div five</p>
            </div>

    <script>
//keep your expire dates in an array in your desired format
   var desiredExpiryDates = [.,......,.,.]

        function expire(){                          
            for(var i=0;i< desiredExpiryDates.length;i++ ){

// find current date and  compare desiredExpiryDates in desired way & compare

            if(currentdate === desiredExpiryDates[i] ){  
            $('#div'+i).hide()
            } else{
            $('#div'+i).show()
            }
            }

   // settimeout callback to check and compare within desired time interval
        setTimeout(expire, 1000);
        }
    </script>
```